# PHP Instance object with path

Tags: php, object, symfony, instance

I'm trying to create an instance of an object with a path like(C:\wamp\www...)

In a new project I have this method, and I try with that to instance an object of an another project.

```
public function getControllerObject($class)
{
    $object =  null;
    $class = realpath($class);  
    $class = str_replace('.php','',$class);

    $object = new $class();

}
```

the variable $class have for exemple this value :

```
C:\wamp\www\myproject\projectBundle\Controller\DefaultController
```

But i get FatalErrorException: `Error: Class. Class not found`

I already try to put 2 backslash but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you trying to create an auto loader or something, because that's what it sounds like.

Comment: Yes i'm trying to get all the controller class of a bundle symfony2. Maybe there is others solution for do this.

Comment: Symfony2 brings its own autoloader. No need to create a new one. Annotate them with a `use` statement and just create them like `$controller = new IndexController();`

Comment: You have an error because you try to create an object from the path `C:\wamp\[...]\Controller\DefaultController
`. The PHP file must be included or called by the autoloader if you want to access it.

Comment: consider adding a `require_once(realpath($class));` statement to your code, then add `$object = new ClassName();`. You can't create an instance of a file, you _can_, however, create an instance of a class definition

Answer (score 1):

Use basename, not realpath:

```
$class = basename($class);
```

For your example it should produce `DefaultController`.

Comment: Ok, but the class is not on the same namespace

Comment: So what is your namespace, the project name? You could use a combination of `basename` and `dirname` to build the dynamic namespace and class string.

Comment: the namespace for the class is myproject\projectBundle\Controller. But my code for instance this object is on a separate project

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what you are trying to do sounds like a horrible idea! If you want to access the class from another project you should add it (the project or the files) to your dependencies.

Your problem is, that what you basically do is:

```
$object = new C:\wamp\www\myproject\projectBundle\Controller\DefaultController();
```

which is obviously not what you want. When you do not enter a valid path (which I assume is what happened) realpath will return false and it won't work either.

You have to somehow determine which part of the path is part of the namespace and which is not. You could do this by also adding the project root, meaning which part to strip from the path or the namespace itself, i.e. the part to keep from the path (assuming you follow the recommendations from PSR-0), which should leave you with what you want (after `str_replace()` a `preg_replace()` or something similar).

**Anyway, the cleanest way to solve your problem (apart from adding a dependency), is to use [Symfony Class Loader](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/index.html) instead of hardcoding paths into your application.**